# NavigationBar title doesn't appear

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar, titlebar

I add NavigationBar programmatically and later added title to it, but it doesn't appear at all. What is the problem here?

```
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 55))
navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 44/255, green: 54/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "AAA"
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

navigationBar appears, but title not. How to fix it?

I've tried this too:

```
navigationBar.topItem?.title = "BBB"
```

nothing again

Comment: sounds like you didn't embed your view controller in a navigation controller. did u ? try this please `if let n = self.navigationController {print("yes") } else { print("no")}`

Comment: You are creating a custom anavigation bar, so your code will not work. you need to create a new UINavigationItem and need to set that item as navigationBar.items.
Code summary-  (Check below Gati's answer)
        let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
        navigationItem.title = "Title1"
        navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this will help you out.

```
// Create the navigation bar
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)) 

// Offset by 20 pixels vertically to take the status bar into account

navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

// Create a navigation item with a title
let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "Title"

// Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

// Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

This code is working for me.

**UPDATE : Swift 4/Swift 5**

```
// Create the navigation bar
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 64))

// Offset by 20 pixels vertically to take the status bar into account

navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

// Create a navigation item with a title
let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
navigationItem.title = "Title"

// Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

// Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

Comment: I found it before I asked the question. Nope. It doesn't work

Comment: @Orkhan Just copy and paste above code in viewDidLoad. And it will definitely work. I just checked.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation bar title is set in the view controller being displayed. Normally this is done in view did load on the view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "AAA"
}
```

**EDIT:** After realising that OP is adding `UINavigationBar` on to `UIViewController` and not using standard `UINavigationController`:

```
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 55))
navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 44/255, green: 54/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
let navigationItem = UINavigationItem.init(title: "AAA")
navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

Comment: I see that you are not using standard `UINavigationController`. Please check my update and this must work for you :)!